# Why is it useful to study spatially inhomogeneous spacetimes?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime

There are many scholars who have dedicated their efforts towards finding solutions to the Einstein Field Equations that are spatially inhomogeneous.

Current cosmological observations indicate that on large scales, matter in the universe is distributed in a spatially homogeneous manner (and isotopic).

So my question is; why would it be useful to study spatially INhomogeneous spacetimes? I mean physically, how could this be useful?

EDIT: I'd also be interested in why it's useful to study spatially inhomogeneous vacuum models.

Comment: Because not everything is large scale cosmology?

Comment: Schwarzschild spacetime is spatially inhomogeneous.

Comment: Chapter 19 of "Relativistic Cosmology" by Ellis, Maarten & MacCallum discusses inhomogeneous cosmology, with a list of motivations in page 419. A sample is: galaxies, clusters and so on are already beyond perturbation theory on FLRW, so one must study full non-linear effects from inhomogeneity; the very early universe might be inohogeneous and there are examples where such inhomogeneity prevents inflation from occurring; the swiss cheese model describes decoupling of small-scale dynamics (galaxies) from large scale structures (expanding spacetime); etc